# Зачем ставить запятую перед "случаем"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

> Ты, случаем, не знаешь, как волшебники предпочитают, чтобы их хоронили?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном предложении слово "случаем" является вводным и выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон.

[**СЛУЧАЕМ / СЛУЧАЙНО,** *вводное слово*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_680) (Грамота.ру).

> *Кокотки комната, а не комсомольца. Ты, **случаем,** уж не душишься ли?* В. Вересаев, Сестры. *Ань! Ты, **случайно,** не видела карбюратор?* В. Шукшин, Светлые души. *Вам никогда, **случайно,** не снилось, что вы едете в кузове ободранного грузовика неизвестно куда, а вокруг вас сидят какие-то монстры?* В. Пелевин, Откровение Крегера. *Вы, **случайно,** не из Москвы?*

См.: [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ВВОДНЫХ СЛОВАХ И СОЧЕТАНИЯХ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).